# d3.js area() under a line using gradient function- x value only covering part of the graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, machine-learning, area

I am trying to create a line graph using d3.js, which takes a csv input and converts it to a data array with the keys x1, x2, class.  Using that data I create a perceptron decision boundary using weights and the gradient function which updates and transitions after each iteration.
This works nicely.
What I am struggling with is the area under the curve, as I want positive values to be blue and negative to be red. The areas move with the line correctly, but something is wrong with the x values as the width of the area doesn't cover the whole graph. It covers about half, and starts about a quarter of the way in (I can't post an image.)
Here is the code I'm using for all of these elements, but I thin I am misunderstanding the way area uses the x attribute;

```
lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return widthScale(d.x1); })
        .y(function(d) { return heightScale(((-d.x1 * w1) - w0)/w2); })
        .interpolate("linear");

    var area = d3.svg.area()
        .x(function(d) { return widthScale(d.x1); })
        .y0(xPos)
        .y1(function(d) { return heightScale(((-d.x1 * w1) - w0)/w2); })
        .interpolate("linear");

    var area2 = d3.svg.area()
        .x(function(d) { return widthScale(d.x1); })
        .y0(heightAlter)
        .y1(function(d) { return heightScale(((-d.x1 * w1) - w0)/w2); })
        .interpolate("linear");

    lineGraph = canvas.append("path")
        .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
        .attr("class", "autoLine")
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1)
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

    shadedArea = canvas.append("path")
        .data([data])
        .attr("d", area)
        .attr("class", "area")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

    shadedAreaPos = canvas.append("path")
        .data([data])
        .attr("d", area2)
        .attr("class", "area2")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find that the root of the problem was the way in which the data array was ordered. I do not fully understand what is happening behind the scenes, but by simply reordering the array in ascending order on the x1 values, it now works correctly. I hope this helps someone.